# MODULE_NOT_FOUND in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-modules, prototypejs

first of all, VERY new to programming.
im trying to decompile a.vpd file to a .json file and found a .js that does that but it gives me this error: (note the example for the code typing is "node parser.js proto_defs.vpd proto_defs.json path/to/tf_proto_def_messages.proto")

```
C:\vg\vcpkg>node parser.js proto_defs.vpd proto_defs.json D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\scripts\protodefs\tf_proto_def_messages.proto
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './selectors/root'
Require stack:
- C:\vg\vcpkg\parser.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\vg\vcpkg\parser.js:5:36)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\vg\\vcpkg\\parser.js' ]
}

Node.js v18.17.1
```

the code of the .js file is

```
'use strict';

if (process.argv.length < 4) {
    console.log('Usage: node parser.js <input> <output> [proto]');
    console.log('Example: node parser.js proto_defs.vpd proto_defs.json path/to/tf_proto_def_messages.proto');
    return;
}

const FS = require('fs');
const Protobuf = require('protobufjs'); // v6.8.3

const INPUT_FILE = process.argv[2]; // 'proto_defs.vpd'
const OUTPUT_FILE = process.argv[3]; // 'proto_defs.json'
const PROTO_FILE = process.argv[4] || 'tf_proto_def_messages.proto';

const TF2Schema = new Protobuf.Root().loadSync(PROTO_FILE, { keepCase: true });
/*
function deleteNulls(proto) {
    Object.keys(proto).forEach(field => {
        if (proto[field] === null)
            delete proto[field];
        else if (Array.isArray(proto[field]) && proto[field].length == 0)
            delete proto[field];
        else if (typeof proto[field] == 'object')
            deleteNulls(proto[field]);
    });
    return proto;
}
*/
const TypeMap = new Map([
    // Types, services and enums must start with an uppercase letter to become available as properties of the
    // reflected types as well (i.e. to be able to use MyMessage.MyEnum instead of root.lookup("MyMessage.MyEnum")).
    // (c) Docs
    [TF2Schema.ProtoDefTypes.DEF_TYPE_QUEST_MAP_NODE,   TF2Schema.CMsgQuestMapNodeDef],
    [TF2Schema.ProtoDefTypes.DEF_TYPE_QUEST_THEME,  TF2Schema.CMsgQuestTheme],
    [TF2Schema.ProtoDefTypes.DEF_TYPE_QUEST_MAP_REGION, TF2Schema.CMsgQuestMapRegionDef],
    [TF2Schema.ProtoDefTypes.DEF_TYPE_QUEST,    TF2Schema.CMsgQuestDef],
    [TF2Schema.ProtoDefTypes.DEF_TYPE_QUEST_OBJECTIVE,  TF2Schema.CMsgQuestObjectiveDef],
    [TF2Schema.ProtoDefTypes.DEF_TYPE_PAINTKIT_VARIABLES,   TF2Schema.CMsgPaintKit_Variables],
    [TF2Schema.ProtoDefTypes.DEF_TYPE_PAINTKIT_OPERATION,   TF2Schema.CMsgPaintKit_Operation],
    [TF2Schema.ProtoDefTypes.DEF_TYPE_PAINTKIT_ITEM_DEFINITION, TF2Schema.CMsgPaintKit_ItemDefinition],
    [TF2Schema.ProtoDefTypes.DEF_TYPE_PAINTKIT_DEFINITION,  TF2Schema.CMsgPaintKit_Definition],
    [TF2Schema.ProtoDefTypes.DEF_TYPE_HEADER_ONLY,  TF2Schema.CMsgHeaderOnly],
    [TF2Schema.ProtoDefTypes.DEF_TYPE_QUEST_MAP_STORE_ITEM, TF2Schema.CMsgQuestMapStoreItem],
    [TF2Schema.ProtoDefTypes.DEF_TYPE_QUEST_MAP_STAR_TYPE,  TF2Schema.CMsgQuestMapStarType]
]);

let proto_defs_file = FS.readFileSync(INPUT_FILE);
let Definitions = Object.create(null), file_position = 0, def_type, num_records, msg_length, proto_msg;

/*
ProtoRecord {
    MsgLength: Uint;
    ProtoMsg: Byte[MsgLength];
}

ProtoDef {
    DefType: Uint;
    NumRecords: Uint;
    Record: ProtoRecord[NumRecords]
}

FileStruct {
    Definitions: ProtoDef[ProtoDefTypes];
}
*/

while (file_position < proto_defs_file.length) {
    def_type = proto_defs_file.readUInt32LE(file_position);
    Definitions[def_type] = [];
    file_position += 4;
    num_records = proto_defs_file.readUInt32LE(file_position);
    file_position += 4;
    let decoder = TypeMap.get(def_type);

    while (num_records--) {
        msg_length = proto_defs_file.readUInt32LE(file_position);
        file_position += 4;
        proto_msg = proto_defs_file.slice(file_position, file_position + msg_length);
        if (decoder) {
            proto_msg = decoder.decode(proto_msg); // enums as strings
            //proto_msg = decoder.toObject(proto_msg, { enums: Number }); // enums as numbers
            Definitions[def_type].push(proto_msg); // deleteNulls(proto_msg)
        } else {
            console.error(`Unknown DefType ${def_type}. Decoder not found!`);
            Definitions[def_type].push(proto_msg.toString('hex'));
        }
        file_position += msg_length;
    }
}

FS.writeFileSync(OUTPUT_FILE, JSON.stringify(Definitions, null, '\t'), 'utf8');
```

i have protobuf,fs installed and parser.js in the right directory.
have a good day!

i have installed (to my knowledge) all the necessary tools (protobufjs,fs,tf_proto_def_messages.proto,vcpkg and git) checked multiple times that the directories are right and contacted multiple people who have already decompiled older version of the proto_defs.vpd file. im sure the problem is a rookie mistake and hope to fix this.